# How can trigonometric functions such as sine and cosine be expressed as infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The trigonometric functions being expressed as an infinite series is something I never really understood. I understand that they can be expressed as infinite series but I never actually understood the proof. Can someone explain how we arrive to the following infinite series? I've never seen the derivation.

$${\sin}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

$${\cos}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

Comment: This is often given as the definitions of $\cos$ and $\sin$.

Comment: One way is to use the power series expansion of the exponential function. Since $\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2},$ for example, the result follows immediately.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've seen the derivation, you just failed to understand it. Naturally, it depends on the definition of the trigonometric functions. *Usually*, those are introduced geometrically, and with geometry, the addition theorems for $\sin$ and $\cos$ are proved, together with inequalities $$\sin x\le x\le\tan x$$ for $x\in[0,\pi/2)$. From there, you can obtain the derivatives of $\cos$ and $\sin$, and that gives the Taylor series. Known theorems show that the latter are globally convergent. So the logical structure is not all that complicated.

Of course, you can as well start from the series, or from the differential equations, and prove that those functions describe the unit circle (and I've seen textbooks doing that), but it's a bit artificial, since most students learned about trigonometric functions before power series or differential equations.

Answer (score 1):

In a calculus course, you will learn about Taylor series.  These are two examples of Taylor series.  So wait until you study calculus; there you will find the derivations for these.

Comment: I've studied the basic and elementary calculus sequence; I'm currently studying differential equations. I figured this is more of a matter of elementary algebra; I haven't had a chance to read Chrystal's Algebra books, which I intend to read, and these cover series and product expansions of the trigonometric functions.

Comment: Look in the index of your calculus textbook for "Taylor series".  The proofs connected with Taylor series often use integration, so this subject is not included in elementary algebra.

Comment: Chrystal is a very old reference. Don't forget that "algebra" meant something very different in the 19th century from what it does today: the definition of the transcendental functions would not be considered as part of algebra today. I would recommend a modern calculus textbook: note that there are design choices to be made about how you define $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes. Should I refer to it as basic arithmetic? I haven't studied modern algebra, but I assume it refers to the developments including abstract algebra.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\cos0 & = 1 \\
\cos'0 & = 0 \\
\cos''0 & = -1 \\
\cos'''0 & = 0 \\
\text{Then repeat} & \text{ this sequence of four.}
\end{align}
$$
The problem then is: If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$ satisfies this same repeating sequence of values of its derivative at $0,$ then what is $c_n \text{?}$ You will find that $c_n$ is $n!$ times the value of the $n$th derivative at $0.$